# Using webclient to download images from deployed website

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, download, webclient

i deployed a website on IIS running on localhost/xxx/xxx.aspx . On my WPF side , i download a textfile using webclient from the localhost server and save it at my wpf app folder 
this is how i do it :

```
  protected void DownloadData(string strFileUrlToDownload)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        byte[] myDataBuffer = client.DownloadData(strFileUrlToDownload);         

        MemoryStream storeStream = new MemoryStream();

        storeStream.SetLength(myDataBuffer.Length);
        storeStream.Write(myDataBuffer, 0 , (int)storeStream.Length);

        storeStream.Flush();

        string currentpath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Folder";

        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(currentpath, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[storeStream.Length];
            storeStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)storeStream.Length);
            file.Write(myDataBuffer, 0, (int)storeStream.Length);
            storeStream.Close();
        }

        //The below Getstring method to get data in raw format and manipulate it as per requirement
        string download = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer);


    }
```

This is by writing btyes and saving them . But how do i download multiple image files and save it on my WPF app folder? I have a URL like this localhost/websitename/folder/designs/ , under this URL , there is many images , how do i download all of them ? and save it on WPF app folder?

Basically i want to download the contents of the folder whereby the contents are actually images.

Comment: Why use `using` on `FileStream`, but not `MemoryStream` or `WebClient`?

Answer (score 1):

First, the `WebClient` class already has a method for this. Use something like `client.DownloadFile(remoteUrl, localFilePath)`.

See this link:

[WebClient.DownloadFile Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx)

Secondly, you will need to index the files you want to download on the server somehow. You can't just get a directory listing over HTTP and then loop through it. The web server will need to be configured to enable directory listing, or you will need a page to generate a directory listing. Then you will need to download the results of that page as a string using `WebClient.DownloadString` and parse it. A simple solution would be an aspx page that outputs a plaintext list of files in the directory you want to download.

Finally, in the code you posted you're saving every single file you download as a file named "Folder". You need to generate a unique filename for each file you want to download. When you're looping through the files you want to download, use something like:

```
string localFilePath = Path.Combine("MyDownloadFolder", imageName);
```

where `imageName` is a unique filename (with file extension) for that file.

Comment: i don't understand what you meant by download the results of the page and parse it , u mean the page where all my images is? but there is no page , its only a folder.

Comment: i can download the file , but its 1 by 1 , i want to to download all of it and save it into a folder

Comment: You can't simply "download all of it" from a web server. This isn't something a web server supports. Unless you know in advance all of the files in that folder, you need to request a list of files from the web server and then use that list to download each file individually.

Why are you even trying to do this? I'm 99% certain that what you're trying to do isn't something you need to be doing, and you're just a new programmer making your own life more difficult.

Comment: but its in my directory.. not in any of my pages.... how do i request them? Downloadstring only download pages?

Comment: _Exactly. Simply put, over HTTP you can only download pages/files._ You need to make your own page on the server that lists the contents of the directory you want. Then, your client will download that page and use the list to download each file individually.